# Метка, которой нет

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено

У [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/201503/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-mail) вопроса 3 метки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда жму "править", то вижу всего 2 метки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Баг?

Comment: При инлайновом редактировании вопроса видно 3 метки, при инлайновом редактировании меток — 2, при простом редактировании вопроса — 2.

Comment: Там для тебя горит очаг...

Comment: @NickVolynkin меньше 10 вопросов )

Comment: @Suvitruf: ноль! http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @NickVolynkin наконец-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересный баг. Вроде получилось починить вопрос, действовал следующим образом:

1. Открыл простое редактирование. Мне были видны все три метки.
2. Удалил метку [ошибка]
3. Добавил метку [баг], которая синонимизирована к [ошибка]
4. Подтвердил правку.

После этого вижу две метки. Описание правки: [[Edit removed during grace period]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/201503/revisions)